# Can I do anything with my spare Swedish nose?

Tags: costume-quest

I originally picked up Costume Quest because I thought it would appeal to my wife, but have recently started playing it myself (seeing how I was wrong).

So I've been running around Auburn Pines beating monsters and collecting Creepy Treats. So far, I've managed to trade all of my redundant cards with kids I met around the neighborhood, with the exception of an excess Swedish nose.

Since I highly doubt that I was simply lucky enough to pick up duplicate cards that the other kids just happened to need, I suspect that the cards collected are in fact predetermined. This leads me to believe that I am supposed to do something with that spare nose, and I don't want to miss my chance once I go through the gate that opened now that I have trick-or-treated all of the houses.

So am I reading too much into this, or is there some kid I missed that I could trade the extra nose with?

Comment: love the title, makes absolutely no sense when taken out of context

Comment: +1 for being wrong about what would appeal to your wife.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to finish the game and get all the achievements/trophies/whatever, the spare swedish nose is of no importance.  It is simply an extra nose.

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember, the cards you collect have no importance in the game other than a kid or two by level that want to trade a specific card with you. So, don't worry too much about the cards.

If you absolutley want to complete all the quests and you don't have the card that the kid asks for, you can continue on your way and come back when you have the required card.